# How can i downgrade Google Play Services Library in Android SDK?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, location-client

The latest update to the Google Play Services Library of the Android SDK removed the LocationClient class from it. How can i downgrade to the previous version so i won't have to rewrite the code to retrieve a client's location?

I do intend to change the code to use the new LocationApi later, but for now, i need a quick fix.

Comment: if you are using eclipse you are out of luck but if you are using android studio just change the gradle version to whatever one you want

Comment: Yeah, sadly i'm still with Eclipse for this project. Never using it again for any future projects, especially since Android Studio 1.0 came out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this site here which has links to mirrors of Android SDK Extras by Google. I downloaded google play services SDK r21 from there and am currently using it.

http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-sdk-extras-by-google-inc.html

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

Go to settings>apps>all and find Google Play Services. Tap it, then tap 'disable' or whatever it is. Then tap on the 'uninstall updates'. After you've installed your version of the services, remember to tap the button 'Take to use' or whatever is displayed.

Comment: This question is related to downgrading the development library, not downgrading Google Play services on a device.

Comment: Like he said, so the answer is actually irrelevant. Still thanks for answering. I found the solution btw, it's in my answer.